# jqGrid - do not display scrollbars

Tags: jqgrid, scrollbar

Is there a way to not display the scrollbars? We'd like to also NOT show the extra space where the scrollbars *would* go if our data didn't fit on the grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `height` and `width` to 100%, and then the scrollbars won’t appear.  They only appear if the grid is larger than the space allocated. To remove the extra space for the bars, set `scrollOffset` to 0.

Here's an example grid definition (corrected version below):

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'datasourceurl',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: eval(json.colNames),
        colModel: eval(json.colModel),
        rowNum: -1,
        width: 100%,
        height: 100%,
        scrollOffset: 0,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: jQuery('#myPager'),
        ...
    },
```

I haven’t tested this, but I use `height: 100%` for the same purpose... so let me know if you see anything missing.

EDIT: A better definition, and improvement on my json usage - thank you Oleg :)

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'datasourceurl',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: JSON.parse(json.colNames),
        colModel: JSON.parse(json.colModel),
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: jQuery('#myPager'),
        ...
    },
```

Comment: In general the suggestion to use 100% width and height is absolutely correct. The values must be quoted ('100%' or "100%"). `eval` is evil. If you need it somewhere you should use `JSON.parse`. It is much faster on all current browsers (see http://www.json.org/js.html) and safe of cause. The usage of `rowNum: -1` is also dangerous. It's depend of the server which you use. Much saver either to use a value from the values `rowList` or a large integer like 10000. The usage of `scrollOffset:0` seems me also not needed. Sorry for so much critic, but I have to write this.

Comment: thank you for posting this fix Oleg, it just helped me correct the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this can be done with `scrollOffset:0`.  Saw this tip [here](http://veechand.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/10-jqgrid-tips-learned-from-my-experience/)

Comment: Sorry Marcus, but I don't understand how the setting of `scrollOffset:0` can helps if you will have no scroll bars **without the setting** also. Try to play with a test page http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing6.htm which has no  `scrollOffset:0`. It use only `width: '100%'` and `height: '100%'`. Could you find an example where you will do see scroll bars?

Comment: If I have no scrollbars there is still a space to the right of the grid where the scrollbar would go if there was add'l data. Setting scrollOffset seems to remove this extra space.

Comment: @Markus: Sorry Markus, but I can only repeat that in my opinion the value of `scrollOffset` parameter is absolutely unimportant at lest together with the settings `width: '100%'` and `height: '100%'` which switch off the scrolling in the jqGrid. Just compare http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing7.htm having `scrollOffset:500` with http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ClientsideEditing6.htm having default value of `scrollOffset`. Do you can see any differences? I can't.